# Why does a memory address only contain 16 bytes of data?

Tags: memory

```
0x8048384 <main+16>: 0x00fc45c7     0x83000000     0x7e09fc7d     0xc713eb02
0x8048394 <main+32>: 0x84842404     0x01e80804     0x8dffffff     0x00fffc45
```

So each memory address contains 16 bytes of data? 4x4 = 16.
So 4 bytes is = 0x00fc45c7

Am I right?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question. Either you read it as 'One memory address contains one byte of data. Per definition. And in the case of PCs that byte is 8 bit wide). Then 0x00fc45c7 is a set of four bytes (0x00, 0xFC, 0x45 and 0xC7) written in a shorter form.  Or you are looking at four sets of 4 bytes per line.

Comment: Hmm ... so it is 8 bytes wide. I thought it was 4 bytes wide. Because you have main incrementing from 16 to 16. Are you sure?

Comment: 4 sets of 4 bytes is 16 bytes (or 0x10 bytes in hexadecimal). 0x80483<b>8</b>4 plus sixteen (0x10) is 0x80483<b>9</b>4

Comment: ok, I think I got it. So 0x00fc45c7 is 4 bytes. And I have 16 bytes total per line. But is this not one memory address? 0x8048384. So in this memory address are stored 16 bytes of data or 0x00fc45c7     0x83000000     0x7e09fc7d     0xc713eb02

Comment: It depends on how you look at a memory address. One way is to look at an address is a single byte. Another way would be to look at it with the width of the databus (in which case a single address is a set of four sequential bytes. All which which can be read simultaneously, and which start at a modulo 4 offset).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't. A specific address in memory generally points to **one** byte of memory. However, your display here is showing you every byte of memory from `0x8048384` to `0x80483A4` - That's 32 bytes of memory, organized into 2 rows of 4 4-byte values.

If you look carefully on the left side, the addresses don't increment by one between the lines, but rather by 16: `84` -> `94` (in base 16), which tells you that there are 16 bytes of memory being displayed on each line. This is often more convenient than 1-byte-per-line, and these 16-byte lines are further broken down into 4-byte groups because it's quite common to use aligned, 32-bit numbers, which each grouping of 4 bytes represents. This makes it easier to visually process the information without resorting to other tools for interpretation.

Comment: I think I get it. So 0x00fc45c7 rests at 0x8048384 and 0x83000000 rests at (0x8048384+4) and so forth. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Addendum: debuggers, disk dump utilities, and similar tools commonly use the sort of display shown. The output COULD be shown as a four-byte address (eight hex digits) followed by a single byte, then another four-byte address (one higher than the previous) followed by another byte, etc. But that would take a lot of space on the display. Displaying  on each line 16 bytes' worth of content along with the address of the first byte is a convenient and widely-understood convention for saving display space while showing enough "landmarks" (addresses) so one doesn't get lost.

Comment: Addendum 2. A memory address does not _contain_ data. A memory address tells where data _is_. The memory _at the address_ contains data.